# Android Admob 4.1.1 has a memory leak (see attached test project). Cause/fix/work around?

Tags: android, memory, memory-leaks, admob, adview

I have a test project which demonstrates a memory leak caused by Admob 4.1.1.

The basic scenario is I have two activities and I switch back and forth between the main and the sub activity several times. I then switch to DDMS and force a few GCs. Then dump the HPROF and look at the historgram filtered by com.test* to see how many instances of the main and sub activity there are. My screenshots of the histogram are attached:

A leak!
[image: leaks]

I then commented out the ads in the xml and reran and there were no leaks:

No leak now
[image: no leak]

I have found some relevant posts to Admob leaks such as here: [Android AdMob causes memory leak?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6148812/android-admob-causes-memory-leak)

Here is a list of things I have tried to resolve the issue:

1. Wait some amount of time and then force gc
2. Do not load the ad in oncreate but spawn a thread to wait then load it
3. Tried a previous version of Admob (the one not written by Google)
4. Called adView.destroy() in the onDestroy() activity's method
5. The unbinding from this [link](http://1gravity.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=71:android-and-memory-leaks&catid=37:android&Itemid=59)

Obviously none of these things helped.

Here is the test project I wrote:

(Be sure to set your own publisher id when you run the test project)

[download test leak android project](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/2309173/TestAdmobLeak.zip)

If it makes a difference I'm tesing on my SGS2 with Cyanogenmod ROM.

Does this happen for other people when they run this project?

Does anyone know the cause a fix or a workaround?

Thanks

Comment: My *best* work-around atm is to use the unbinding which I mentioned in the post. This minimizes the footprint of the leaked activities so that you can have hundreds of them open without getting OOMs. Not exactly ideal :(

Comment: See my solution here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6148812/android-admob-causes-memory-leak/8364820#8364820

Comment: Im not sure if that helps but I created a bug on Android support site. Admob is currently held by Google so they should do something about it. I was pretty supprised that this bug wasn't there already. [ISSUE 59627](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=59627&thanks=59627&ts=1378046413)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My app uses 80% of the allowed 16Mb and the AdView leaks at every orientation change (since android destroys and recreates the whole activity then). As a result I am out of memory after a dozen or so orientation changes giving me the dreaded:

10-08 10:14:47.178: ERROR/dalvikvm-heap(2876): 1440000-byte external allocation too large for this process.

10-08 10:14:47.178: ERROR/dalvikvm(2876): Out of memory: Heap Size=5191KB, Allocated=2877KB, Bitmap Size=18675KB

10-08 10:14:47.178: ERROR/GraphicsJNI(2876): VM won't let us allocate 1440000 bytes

or similar.

The increase in memory can easily be seen in eclipse by doing a debug run and opening Window > Open perspective > Other > DDMS, clicking the "update heap" icon and doing a Cause GC. The easiest way to check imho is the #Objects. If the orientation has changed from portrait to landscape and back, the number of Objects should be exactly the same (and without AdView it is).

I work around the memory leak by making the AdView static

```
private static AdView mAdView = null;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if(mAdView == null)
    {
        mAdView = new AdView(this, AdSize.BANNER, ADMOB_PUBLISHER_ID);
    }
}
```

and not calling the destroy

```
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    //mAdView.destroyDrawingCache();
    //mAdView.destroy();
    //mAdView = null;
}
```

At least this prevents memory leaks between every orientation change.

Also I set request to null after using it. Don't know if that helps.

```
    AdRequest request = new AdRequest();
    mAdView.loadAd(request);
    request = null;
```

Comment: Do you programmatically add the AdView to your layout then? I created a LinearLayout to hold the AdView and proceeded as you did and there were no more leaks, but the ads were not clickable either and it was a bit of a pain detatching the static AdView from the previous views before it could be reused.

Comment: I suddenly started seeing the out of memory messages after I updated to a new Eclipse (I know, that shouldn't matter). I was using an Admob library from 2010. I upgraded to Admob 4.3.1, which required me to change all my Android Admob code. Now, I do not see any errors.

Answer (score 1):

My solution

```
private void destroyWebView(ViewGroup viewGroup) {
for (int i = 0; i < viewGroup.getChildCount(); i++) {
    if (viewGroup.getChildAt(i) instanceof WebView) {
        WebView view = (WebView) viewGroup.getChildAt(i);
        viewGroup.removeView(view);
        view.destroy();
        return;
    }
}
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
mAdView.stopLoading();
destroyWebView(mAdView);
((ViewGroup) mAdView.getParent()).removeView(mAdView);
```

Answer (score -1):

Yes, I build it all up dynamically. I use removeAllViews to remove all views from my (LinearLayout) container. Then I use addView to put them all back again.
The ad is clickable. Is there perhaps some transparent view in front of it in your case?