# Admob Android memory leak issue - Howto remove activity from memory

Tags: android, admob

I have simple network counter application, which has two parts A service and a view.
I have a memory leak issue with my application. First I will explain my app briefly.

**Service part**

Service costs 2-3 Mb and in runs evertime. (starts with BOOT_COMPLETED and never die)
It sends statictics to server periodically. And I dont have a memory problem with Service.

**Activity part**

I have a, 1 layout very simple view that shows statictics to user.
If I dont add an Adview on it this view costs 3 Mb and no memory leak.
If I add a AdView on it, it costs 9 Mb(11Mb with Service) on memory and CONTINUE TO GROW on every pause/resume of activity. At the and I guess system kills whole application including service And this is very bad news.

I want to completely remove this Activity when not in use. (leaving Service alive.)

**How can I completely remove Activity from memory apart from service?**

I guess I should have some workaround in my case.

**Notes:**

I dont need orientation change. it is set to portrait. 
btw, I really dont understand this is not fixed yet in Admob.
Here is some other resources I have tried.

[Android Admob 4.1.1 has a memory leak (see attached test project). Cause/fix/work around?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7695576/android-admob-4-1-1-has-a-memory-leak-see-attached-test-project-cause-fix-wor)

[Android AdMob causes memory leak?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6148812/android-admob-causes-memory-leak)

http://1gravity.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=71:android-and-memory-leaks&catid=37:android&Itemid=59

Comment: I'd like to see this investigated a little more. The Java gc should be able to remove all objects that are not "live", so in cases of a memory leak, there usually is some thread running which keeps a reference to old objects. Can we see if we find out about any threading in Admob using DDMS etc.?

Comment: I have this issue too. It is said that the AdView keeps a reference to the activity, but this does not explain why the RAM usage continues to grow...

Comment: I also have this issue on the SDK 4.3.2, and there is no way to contact them... on their site it says that the contacting page could not be found... funny...