# Activity Does not launch from the recent activities:- Android

Tags: android, admob, illegalstateexception

I am trying to implement ads in my android application. I suspected memory leaks when i added ads to my xml layout so i tried the approach described in this post :- [Admob Memory Leak - avoiding by using empty activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9558708/admob-memory-leak-avoiding-by-using-empty-activity)

The ads are rendered and there is no problem except that if in between my app's screens, if i click on home button of the device accidently and then if i go to recent applications and select mine, I get the error :-

```
03-22 22:17:56.604: E/AndroidRuntime(27206): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: This activity should be created only once during the entire application life
03-22 22:17:56.604: E/AndroidRuntime(27206):    at com.xyz.watch.AdMobActivity.<init>(AdMobActivity.java:16)
03-22 22:17:56.604: E/AndroidRuntime(27206):    at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
03-22 22:17:56.604: E/AndroidRuntime(27206):    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1409)
03-22 22:17:56.604: E/AndroidRuntime(27206):    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1021)
03-22 22:17:56.604: E/AndroidRuntime(27206):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1561)
03-22 22:17:56.604: E/AndroidRuntime(27206):    ... 11 more
03-22 22:17:56.684: W/System.err(27206): java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/plog.log (Permission denied)
```

The launch mode of my AdMobActivity is singleInstance so maybe thats the reason. What should i do for this to work?

Update :- My code

Inside my first launch activity (MainActivity)

```
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    DatabaseAdapter databaseAdapter = new DatabaseAdapter(
            getApplicationContext());
    databaseAdapter.open();
    databaseAdapter.close();
}

    @Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    if (AdMobActivity.AdMobMemoryLeakWorkAroundActivity == null) {
        Log.i("CHAT", "starting the AdMobActivity");
        AdMobActivity.startAdMobActivity(this);
    }
}
```

AdMobActivity:-

```
public final class AdMobActivity extends Activity {

public static AdMobActivity AdMobMemoryLeakWorkAroundActivity;

public AdMobActivity() {
    super();
    if (AdMobMemoryLeakWorkAroundActivity != null) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("This activity should be created only once during the entire application life");
    }
    AdMobMemoryLeakWorkAroundActivity = this;
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Log.i("CHAT", "in onCreate - AdMobActivity");
    finish();
}

public static final void startAdMobActivity(Activity activity) {
    Log.i("CHAT", "in startAdMobActivity");
    Intent i = new Intent();
    i.setComponent(new ComponentName(activity.getApplicationContext(), AdMobActivity.class));
    activity.startActivity(i);
}
```

}

Line no. 16 is

```
 throw new IllegalStateException("This activity should be created only once during the entire application life");
```

Comment: have u tried to move Admob related code inside onResume method?

Comment: no.. let me try to do that..

Comment: no... still the same error

Comment: i will paste my code here...

Comment: @TacB0sS Please help.. I think this was your solution originally so you might be able to help

Comment: what is line number 16 in AdMobActivity.java?

Comment: Updated my code to add AdMobActivity

Comment: what do you mean by "if in between my app's screens". When exactly does this error occur?

Comment: By in between i mean... on any other activity except the splash screen where i create the AdMobActivity

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at this code. i have used this only. i didnt faced any memory leaks.

http://jmsliu.com/209/add-google-admob-in-android-application.html

hope this will help you.

have a try with this code also. this doesn't to integrate in xml layout. just do it pro grammatically.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams;

import com.google.ads.*;

public class AdmobExample extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    private AdView myAdView;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        myAdView = new AdView(this, AdSize.BANNER, "youradmob id. ");

        //get layoutView
        LinearLayout rootView = (LinearLayout)this.findViewById(R.id.rootViewGroup);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LayoutParams(480, 75);

        rootView.addView(myAdView, 0, layoutParams);        

        AdRequest re = new AdRequest();
        re.setGender(AdRequest.Gender.FEMALE);
        //re.setTestDevices(testDevices);
        //re.setTesting(testing)

        myAdView.loadAd(re);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey thanks.. i will try this. In this example you r sending the gender information in the request. How are you doing so.. Is it possible to get gender information of user?