# My interstitial Ad is causing a memory leak?

Tags: java, android, memory-leaks, interstitial

I also tried using the `ApplicationContext` but it still leaks for some reason.

Found a similar post about the issue here [AdActivity leak on AdMob (SDK 7.0) for Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29252545/adactivity-leak-on-admob-sdk-7-0-for-android#comment106773604_29252545) but without an answer.

Also tried to set the adlistener and the ad to null in onDestroy() but without any luck and still leaks the activity.

**My code called in onCreate()**

```
private void refreshInterstitial(){
        mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);
        mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId("AD_ID");
        mInterstitialAd.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR).addTestDevice("877BCC97E130A0DC62B2E5770D854496").build());

        mInterstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAdLoaded() {
                mInterstitialAd.show();
            }
            @Override
            public void onAdClosed() {
            }
        });
}
```

**Leakcanary Leak Trace**

```
 ┬───
    │ GC Root: Global variable in native code
    │
    ├─ mx instance
    │    Leaking: UNKNOWN
    │    ↓ mx.a
    │         ~
    ├─ com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.webview.w instance
    │    Leaking: UNKNOWN
    │    mContext instance of com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.webview.ay, not wrapping activity
    │    View#mParent is null
    │    View#mAttachInfo is null (view detached)
    │    View.mWindowAttachCount = 1
    │    ↓ w.a
    │        ~
    ├─ com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.webview.aa instance
    │    Leaking: YES (View detached and has parent)
    │    mContext instance of com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.webview.ay, not wrapping activity
    │    View#mParent is set
    │    View#mAttachInfo is null (view detached)
    │    View.mWindowAttachCount = 1
    │    ↓ aa.mListenerInfo
    ├─ android.view.View$ListenerInfo instance
    │    Leaking: YES (aa↑ is leaking)
    │    ↓ View$ListenerInfo.mOnClickListener
    ├─ com.google.android.gms.ads.nonagon.ad.webview.f instance
    │    Leaking: YES (aa↑ is leaking)
    │    ↓ f.a
    ├─ com.google.android.gms.ads.nonagon.ad.webview.l instance
    │    Leaking: YES (aa↑ is leaking)
    │    ↓ l.e
    ├─ com.google.android.gms.ads.nonagon.ad.event.bs instance
    │    Leaking: YES (aa↑ is leaking)
    │    ↓ bs.a
    ├─ java.util.HashMap instance
    │    Leaking: YES (aa↑ is leaking)
    │    ↓ HashMap.table
    ├─ java.util.HashMap$Node[] array
    │    Leaking: YES (aa↑ is leaking)
    │    ↓ HashMap$Node[].[1]
    ├─ java.util.HashMap$Node instance
    │    Leaking: YES (aa↑ is leaking)
    │    ↓ HashMap$Node.key
    ├─ com.google.android.gms.ads.nonagon.shim.k instance
    │    Leaking: YES (aa↑ is leaking)
    │    ↓ k.a
    ├─ com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.client.ae instance
    │    Leaking: YES (aa↑ is leaking)
    │    ↓ ae.a
    ├─ com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzuc instance
    │    Leaking: YES (aa↑ is leaking)
    │    ↓ zzuc.zzcbw
    ├─ com.test.Activity$1 instance
    │    Leaking: YES (aa↑ is leaking)
    │    Anonymous subclass of com.google.android.gms.ads.AdListener
    │    ↓ EqualizerActivity$1.this$0
    ╰→ com.test.Activity instance
    ​     Leaking: YES (ObjectWatcher was watching this because Activity received Activity#onDestroy() callback and Activity#mDestroyed is true)
    ​     key = 40a1eb8e-c9e6-4062-b5f7-053e642e812f
    ​     watchDurationMillis = 5288
    ​     retainedDurationMillis = 258
```

Comment: Have you tried making `mInterstitialAd` a local variable instead?

Comment: @harrytmthy Why would that solve the problem?

Comment: Because in most cases memory leak happened when we keep a reference of a mutable object, where this reference is NOT lifecycle aware. When `AdListener` callback is called, somehow your `mInterstitialAd` is being leaked. That's why I am asking you to turn it into a local variable instead, and make it `final` to ensure its immutability. That way, you can prevent the memory leak.

Comment: And if that's the case, please let me know so I can write it as an answer and claim the bounty :)

Comment: @harrytmthy just tried it and it's still leaking

Comment: See my answer :)

Comment: happened with me too. Seems like bug from their side

Comment: @SahilManchanda That's what i thought, but why is no one reporting this. I can barely find anything about this here on stackoverflow and on their community page they don't answer my questions.

Comment: Have you browsed some of the issues on https://github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-android-examples? Does [issue #83](https://github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-android-examples/issues/83) or [issue #84](https://github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-android-examples/issues/84) look similar?

Comment: @kasptom yes except i'm just using a basic interstitial ad and not a rewarded video but i just looked at the comments and someone has the exact same problem on #84.

Answer (score 3):

According to [InterstitialAd Docs](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/interstitial#create_an_interstitial_ad_object):

> A single InterstitialAd object can be used to request and display multiple interstitial ads over the course of an activity's lifespan, **so you only need to construct it once**.

After looking at your code again, I noticed you re-construct `mInterstitialAd` every time `refreshInterstitial()` method is called. But according to the docs above, you should only construct `mInterstitialAd` once during `onCreate()`.

In your case, **the main cause of the memory leak:** you still have an active listener (which is bound to Activity lifespan), yet you reconstruct a new `InterstitialAd` instance with another listener.

So, the solution is to reuse `InterstitialAd` instance and its listener without re-assigning. I suggest to simplify your `refreshInterstitial()` method to this:

```
private void refreshInterstitial() {
    mInterstitialAd.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR).addTestDevice("877BCC97E130A0DC62B2E5770D854496").build());
}
```

Then put `mInterstitialAd` assignment to `onCreate()`. This solution is similar to the one you can find [here](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/interstitial#using_an_adlistener_to_reload).

Comment: I don't understand this? My method refreshInterstitial() is the code that is called in onCreate() when i launch my activity so it is called once. Also without the adlistener the interstitial won't show up because i have to call mInterstitialAd.show() when the ad is loaded.

Comment: Now let me ask you: do you only call `refreshInterstitial()` only once in the whole Activity lifespan? Because if you call it more than once, with your code, memory leak will happen.

Comment: Once. I just put it inside a method because i have alot of code in my onCreate

Comment: Then can you update your question, show us what's inside your `onCreate()` so we can figure out the solution? Because the Leak Trace logged `Leaking: YES (ObjectWatcher was watching this because Activity received Activity#onDestroy() callback and Activity#mDestroyed is true)`. Which means there is a part in your code which triggers `onDestroy()` then re-create the Activity, making your `InterstitialAd` constructed more than once.

Comment: Thats because i go back to my previous activity, Activity is a second activity and not my mainactivity. So when i press the back button ObjectWatcher is destroyed and that's normal.

Comment: I think this is a bug on their side unfortunately. Even their github example which is from google itself has this leak.

Answer (score 2):

This is working for me: (in ActivityMain()):

```kotlin
MobileAds.initialize(WeakReference(applicationContext).get()){}
```

in fragments:

```kotlin
adView= AdView(WeakReference(requireActivity().application).get())
```

LeakCanary shows:

====================================
HEAP ANALYSIS RESULT
====================================
0 APPLICATION LEAKS.

Comment: I'm the 2nd person who upvoted this answer but upon further testing this answer doesn't work. **Don't use it**

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same issue in interstitial ad and it is resolved by setting the FullScreenContentCallback to null in all of its overridden methods.

```
 interstitial.setFullScreenContentCallback(new FullScreenContentCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onAdDismissedFullScreenContent() {
            super.onAdDismissedFullScreenContent();
            
            interstitial.setFullScreenContentCallback(null);}}
```

Comment: I know my memory leak is related to this specific setting with the FullScreenContentCallback. However, I'm still getting memory leaks even after setting this to null.